Running a PySpark zip project using Spark-Submit
I'm trying to run my PySpark project which is written in modules. The project looks like this: project structure
pipeline/
├── code
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── driver.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── io
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── input_output.py
│   │   ├── pipeline
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── my_pipeline.py
│   │   ├── schema
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── my_types.py
│   │   │   └── schema_repository.py
│   │   └── transform
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── transformer.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── setup.py
│   └── test
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── test_base.py
│       └── test_transformer
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── test_transformer.py
└── requirements.txt

As you can see, the driver is located in /pipeline/code/core.
To run the project from the project root (pipeline/), I run:
python -m code.core.driver

And I create the zip file of the project using setup-tools:
setup(name='ppl',
      version='0.0.1',
      description='Sample pyspark project',
      packages=find_packages())

But when I try to run the project using spark-submit:
spark-submit --master "local[*]"  --py-files code/dist/pipeline-people-0.0.1.zip  code.core.driver

I get the following error:
Exception in thread main org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get main class in JAR with error 'File file:/home/maral/PycharmProjects/pipeline/code.core.driver does not exist'.  Please specify one with --class.
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.error(SparkSubmit.scala:1047)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:528)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:964)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1129)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)`

How can I fix this error?
